# screen effect with gd2

Tags: php, image, gd2

Is it possible to insert watermark to another photo with screen effect (similar like in Photoshop) using PHP with gd2? I was looking for something like that in PHP manual and google, but I only found imagelayereffect and imagefilter function and these don't have screen effect

Comment: Take a look at this: [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/watermark-images-php/)

Comment: good idea but it is without effects. I found somethng like this: [link](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Tools/docs/latest/Image_Tools/_Image_Tools-1.0.0RC1---Image---Tools---Blend.php.html)